# Gradle ivy service MetaDataParseException

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I am a gradle noob, I have the following gradle configuration in my project. I am trying to set up an AmazonBeanStalk java spring project.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'
 }
 repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    mavenLocal()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'


sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


war {
 baseName = 'videosvc-amazon-beanstalk'
 version =  '1.1'
}

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
 maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
 maven { url "http://repo.opensourceagility.com/snapshots" }
}

dependencies {

 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
 providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

 compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.8.0.RELEASE")

 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
 compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.1.0.RELEASE")

 compile("org.socialsignin:spring-data-dynamodb:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT")

 compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
 compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")
 compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")

 testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
 gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

When I do a gradle build, I get the following parse exception. I have no clue where to start, any input would be much appreciated.

> Could not resolve javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.FINAL.
>     Required by:
>         :MyApp:unspecified > org.socialsignin:spring-data-dynamodb:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final Errors: bad version: expected='1.1.0.FINAL' found='1.1.0.Final'
>   Could not resolve javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.FINAL.
>     Required by:
>         :MyApp:unspecified > org.socialsignin:spring-data-dynamodb:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT > org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final
>   inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final Errors: bad version: expected='1.1.0.FINAL' found='1.1.0.Final'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what does it have to do with *ivy*. The problem is that one of the dependencies, namely:

`org.socialsignin:spring-data-dynamodb:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

depends transitively (via `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final`) on

`javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.FINAL`

which is incorrectly specified, should be (which is visible in output log):

`javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final` (taken from maven central).

The solution is to add dependency for validation explicitly (with appropriate scope):

```
dependencies {
   //...
   compile("javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final")
   //...
}
```